# How to properly install Ubuntu on my new PC

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

I got a new lenovo PC pre installed with windows 8.1 and I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu. I tried using the Live USB/DVD option. It would show an option to choose between windows 8 & Ubuntu and when I choose Ubuntu it will show me an error screen. I didn't want persist because I don't want to screw it up, it being new and all.

What steps should I follow to properly install Ubuntu safely and smoothly?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the error message say? You definitely won't screw it up if you only run Ubuntu off the USB key.

Answer (score 0):

To dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) guide.

As long as you carefully follow the steps, there should not be any issues.

For a more detailed guide with screenshots and easier for beginners, check out [this](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) page.

Comment: please avoid giving external links. You may write portions of it in this answer and provide the source. But simply giving links might cause problems in cases of link rot.